# Excel conditional formatting with gradient colors on Mac

Tags: excel, colors, gradient, conditional-formatting

I was trying to achieve this on Excel, which markers all cells containing "A" a red/green background with a gradient pattern.
I achieved this in the past but now I forgot how I did it.
[image]

[image]

Does anyone know?

Comment: I don't believe you can do that in the current Mac versions.

Comment: @Rory why do they want to abolish that function???

Comment: I don't actually remember if you could do it in the 2011 version. It's not something I've ever wanted anyway. :)

Comment: @Rory I want it because I ran out of colors that can be distinguished by human eyes

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to this, but I forgot how to do this also, so in case anyone else was looking for the answer, on home tab go over to the Format Section of the ribbon and click the drop down arrow for Conditional Formatting.  You will see the options there.  I have attached a screen shot. [Conditional Formatting Excel Mac 2011](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL0oD.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).